# PHP + Form(html)

Tags: php, html, mvc

У меня есть класс контроллер в котором находится метод для создания новой записи в БД. Как в html form указать чтобы вызывать именно конкретный метод который нужно в action через метод post, а не только указание файла.

```
<form action="Controller.php" id="form" method="post">
            <div class="task">
                <div class="pathtask">
                    <div class="photoprofile"><img src="files/profile.png" alt=""><br>Guest</div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="poloca">  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="formpath" name="Name" id="Name"></div>
                        <div class="poloca"><input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="formpath" name="email" id="email"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="texttask">
                    <div contenteditable="true" class="textarea" align="left" name="text" id="texts">
                        Введите текст..
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="knopka">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

controller.php

```
<?php
require_once ('Task.php');
class Taskcontroller extends Task{

    public function GetTask(){
        $tasks=$this->list();
        $view=ShowTasks::getInstance();
        $view->PrintAllTask($tasks);
    }

    public function CreateTask(){
        $this->name=$_POST['name'];
        $this->email=$_POST['email'];
        $this->text=$_POST['text'];
        var_dump($this->name);
    }
}
```

index.php

Comment: Вам нужно разработать систему роутов + у вас же должен создаваться экземпляр объекта Taskcontroller

Comment: Добавь конструктор, сделай свой метод статическим, добавь дополнительный инпут с именем метода в свою форму и прописывай в конструкторе что-то типа `return self::$method();`

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сопоставить url и метод класса-контроллера вам необходим роутер. Если вы используете какой-то готовый фрэймворк, то роутер там уже есть, если пишете что-то своё, то вам надо реализовать роутер.

Вот очень упрощённый пример кода, надеюсь это подтолкнёт вас в правильном направлении.

```
<?php // index.php

// php -S localhost:8000

$requestMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']?? 'UNKNOWN';
$requestUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?? '';
$requestPath = parse_url($requestUrl, PHP_URL_PATH);

$router = new Router([
    'GET /' => 'IndexController::index',
    'POST /tasks' => 'Taskcontroller::CreateTask',
]);
try {
    $func = $router->route("$requestMethod $requestPath");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Что-то пошло не так: ' . $e->getMessage();die;
}
$func();

// -------------------

class Router
{
    
    private $routes;

    public function __construct(array $routes)
    {
        $this->routes = $routes;
    }

    public function route(string $requestId): callable
    {
        $func = null;
        foreach ($this->routes as $requestPattern => $controllerMethodName) {
            if ($requestPattern === $requestId) {
                [$controllerName, $methodName] = explode('::', $controllerMethodName);
                try {
                    $controller = new $controllerName();
                } catch (Throwable $t) {
                    throw new Exception("404 не удалось инстанцировать класс контроллера $controllerName", 1, $t);
                }
                $func = [$controller, $methodName];
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( ! $func) {
            throw new Exception("404 не найден подходящий маршрут", 1);
        }

        return $func;
    }
}

class IndexController
{
    
    public function index()
    {
        echo '
            Index page<br>
            <form action="/tasks" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="foo">
                <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
            </form>
        ';
    }

}

class Taskcontroller
{
    
    public function CreateTask()
    {
        var_dump($_POST);
    }

}
```